# All permutations, and find the lowest number c++

Tags: c++, std, permutation

I'm programming c++ and i want to do this:

My input:

```
213
```

I want to create all permutations and generate the lowest number. Like:

```
123 -> lowest number
132
231
213
312
321
```

I can use, `next_permutation (std library)`, but, is that the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is that a bottle-neck in your program? Why do you need it to be "efficient"? And what do you mean by "efficient"? Speed? Computing resources? Code size? Something else?

Comment: Yeah, the standard library is usually the most efficient way to solve problems, because it's highly optimized and chances are the programmers who implemented the stdlib are way more experienced than you are. But anyway, **why would you care about "efficiency" for a 3-element list?**

Comment: 3 element list, is just an example. Now if you have a 100 digit number, it would be difficult ( very slow) to get the lowest number by doing all permutations. As you are the smartest guy in the world, you know all of this. @TheParamagneticCroissant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No like Kerrek SB said you can just sort it and take that (ascending by default).

```
std::vector<int> input = {
    4, 3, 9, 1
};
std::sort(std::begin(input), std::end(input));
```

For more info see: [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). If you really need all the permutations you  could use `std::next_permutation` on the sorted input and it would always be the first one.

Comment: @ShauryaChats What number? This should really be working: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f0644941576fef9